# Django Annotate and aggregate behaviour clarification. Auto filtering?

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Im writing an API in DRF and had some questions on the behaviour of annotate and aggregate on query sets.
So I essentially have models Product, Producer,  and a model inventory. An inventory contains a product fk, producer fk and quantity and price fields, among other unimportant fields.

I have a view which lists out all the inventory items, and filters them based on producer.
Im trying to annotate the query set to aggregate and sum the quantity of each product among all inventory items. Initially I just referenced the quantity field directly.
That way works apparently, however Im suspicious because it works even if I don't specify that it needs to filter entries based on product.
For safety, I access the product model from the inventory model, and then did a reverse relationship from product back to inventory, and referenced the quantity to be aggregated.

I get the same expected values, and in this way I understand why its working, however it feels inefficient. I need some clarification on why the simple solution works, and if I should use it, since nowhere am I filtering my product, however the aggregated values are aggregated based on product.

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
    item_ID = models.UUIDField(...)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, reverse = 'inventory')
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Producer)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(...)
    ...


class Product(models.Model)
    product_ID = models.UUIDField(...)
    ...


class Producer(models.Model):
    producerID = models.UUIDField(...)



class InventoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # INEFFICIENT SOLUTION
    # Here I visit product model, then reverse back to inventory model and access quantity. Results are as expected.

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
        
        producer = self.request.query_params.get('producer')
        analytics = self.request.query_params.get('analytics')

        if analytics is not None:
               queryset = Inventory.objects.annotate(
                total_quantity = Sum('product__inventory__quantity',filter = Q(producer__online_status = True)),)

        if producer is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(producer = producer)
    ...

    # SIMPLE SOLUTION
    # Here I will simplyy access the quantity field directly. Results are unchanged.

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
        producer = self.request.query_params.get('producer')
        analytics = self.request.query_params.get('analytics')

        if analytics is not None:
               queryset = Inventory.objects.annotate(
                total_quantity = Sum('quantity',filter = Q(producer__online_status = True)),)

        if producer is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(producer = producer)
    ...
```

Comment: What does the query look like if you print `Inventory.objects.annotate(
                total_quantity = Sum('quantity',filter = Q(producer__online_status = True)).query`